# What is the most efficient way of toggling a DOM elements value based on the state of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Imagine we have a text field that executes the code below on each keydown event:

```
if( $('#my_input').val() == '' )
  $('#my_span').html('my input is blank');
else
  $('#my_span').html('My input is not blank');
```

Obviously we are executing code that possibly sets the state of something (`#my_span` element) to what it already is and this seems inefficient. But I am curious as to what the alternative is? Adding more checks like:

```
if ( $('#my_input').val() == '' ){
  if ( $('#my_span').html() != 'my input is blank' )
       $('#my_span').html('my input is blank');
}
else if ( $('#my_span').html() != 'My input is not blank' )
          $('#myspan').html('My input is not blank');
```

Is the latter more efficient? It would seem to me more 'correct', but obviously it's more code and I'm not sure how much more efficient it is than the first example.

I know that the former always involves a DOM manipulation, which will factor in computing the relative efficiency, but I've encountered situations like this before in non-DOM related code, so wondering what is the best approach in all cases. Should you always do the extra check on the value of something before setting it to a new value?

**EDIT:**

My final version actually uses a combination of the answers here so thanks to all for the great replies. So to sum, I now:

- Cache the jquery objects in a closure
- Uses state to determine the assignment to a new state

Also as an aside, the setTimeout on the keydown is a very nice way to get a input fields value immediately. Thanks again.

Comment: You could 1) cache elements, 2) use a boolean to store the state and not call `html` when you don't have to.

Comment: `SOMESTRING == ""` can be replaced by `!SOMESTRING`

Comment: Ha. Every answer has gone through 100 iterations based on comments and comparing and they are all almost identical now. How funny.

Comment: Ha Indeed :) I always leave a gap between an accept as the answers progressively get better :P. I feel this question could still have a better title however. One that is more general? If anyone can think of a better one please edit.

Comment: I think you should be careful in trying to generalise this too much. As it stands, the question is leaning heavily on the DOM, which is _expensive_ to query and manipulate, hence the scope for a more efficient method. If you are simply manipulating strings, for instance, then your code optimisation could be very different, as "caching" and storing "state" could just add complexity and make the method less efficient.

Comment: Well I was looking for a more general best practice answer initially, but I suppose the example allowed for a very specified approach that should be useful to others. My only worry is whether or not its a very searchable title, although coming up with a concise one for this topic is no mean feat. That was why my initial title was so vague by the way! Oh and thank you for the current title edit. It is obviously a good improvement :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would cache the jQuery objects and use a boolean to store the state and not call `html` when you don't have to :

```
(function(){
   var i = $('#my_input'), s=$('#my_span'), blank, check = function() {
      if (i.val()=='') {
         if (blank!==true) s.html('my input is blank');
         blank = true;
      } else {
         if (blank!==false) s.html('my input is not blank');
         blank = false;
      }
   };
   i.keyup(check);
   check(); // so that the span is initially filled
})();
```

Note that what you need isn't `keydown` but `keyup`, so that the value of the input is changed before you get the event.

Answer (score 4):

## This method even works if you keep pressing the key ;)

Performance? Go Pure JS. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZ85H/)

```
//before event binding
var my_input = document.getElementById('my_input'),
  my_span = document.getElementById('my_span');

$(my_input).on('keydown', function () {
  //inside event handler
  var value = my_input.value
  , prevVal = my_input.prevVal
  ;

  if (value && prevVal && prevVal !== value) {
    return;
  }

  //timeout to return event handler execution early 
  //(ie: differ DOM manipulation from the event handler. 
  //So, UX will extra smooth ;) )
  setTimeout(function () {
    fieldStatusUpdater(my_input.value);
  }, 1);

});

function fieldStatusUpdater(value) {
  if (my_input.value === '') {
    my_span.innerHTML = 'my input is blank';
  } else {
    my_span.innerHTML = 'My input is not blank';
  }
  my_input.prevVal = value;
}
```

---

Answer (score 4):

This is the fastest and nicest I can come up with:

```
function keyUpEvent(){
    var state = null,
        input = $('#my_input'),
        span = $('#my_span');

    return function(){
        var test = input.val() === '';
        if( test === state) return;
        if(test)
          span.html('my input is blank');
        else
          span.html('My input is not blank');
        state = test;
    }
}
$('#my_input').keyup(keyUpEvent());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMb8T/

This uses closures to store the input and span elements after initialization. And you can use it (almost) as if its a normal function, so u can bind it do multiple events and it still works. 
Note that you have to execute `keyUpEvent` when you bind the event.

**Addition:**
You can now also do something like this:

```
function keyUpEvent(input, span){
    var state = null;

    return function(){
        var test = input.val() === '';
        if( test === state) return;
        if(test)
            span.html('My input is blank');
        else
            span.html('My input is not blank');
        state = test;
    }
}


$('#my_input').keyup( keyUpEvent($('#my_input'), $('#my_span')) );
$('#my_input2').keyup( keyUpEvent($('#my_input2'), $('#my_span2')) );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMb8T/2/

Like this you can easily check every input of a whole form with one single event handler.

**Addition 2:** If you want to make version 2 work even when the key is kept down ;)

Replace this:

```
$('#my_input').keyup( keyUpEvent($('#my_input'), $('#my_span')) );
```

With this:

```
$('#my_input').keydown(function(){
    setTimeout(keyUpEvent($('#my_input'), $('#my_span')),1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMb8T/4/

Comment: This is also a nice solution. Upvoted. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You should keep the closure idea in the second example too. It's a really nice approach! Kudos.

Comment: Thanks! The second example uses the same closure. We just don't have to store `input`and `span` separately because by passing them as parameters they're already available in the local scope of the closure - see: `keyUpEvent(input, span){`

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how often you are executing the code.  If it executes only when the user presses a button or something like that it would be fine to use the first one, it it runs on a quick timer then it might not.

Do like this:

```
var text;
if ( $('#my_input').val() == '' )
    text = 'my input is blank';
else 
    text = 'My input is not blank';

if ( $(#my_span).html() != text )
    $('#my_span').html(text);
```

Comment: you have conversed the question by adding one more 'if statement' and var text(both unnecessary in your case)

Comment: @Ankit Its the same number of 'if' statements. 2 get executed every time through the code.

Comment: @LeeMeador in question one is executed every time through the code

Comment: @Ankit You are looking at the 1st example. I am looking at the more efficient 2nd example that avoids disturbing the DOM every time through. Trading an 'if' for a change to the DOM seems a good tradeoff to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it with a ternary

```
$('#my_span').html( $('#my_input').val() == '' ? 'my input is blank' : 'My input is not blank' );
```

More readable

```
var text = $('#my_input').val() == '' ? 'my input is blank' : 'My input is not blank';
$('#my_span').html(text);
```

And it you care about speed, it comes up is a DOM redraw faster that reading content. That really will depend on the page strucutre/size,browser. JSPerf is your friend if you want to see how many milliseconds you will save with 1000's of iterations. You really should be looking for the fastest if you see a performance problem.

1. No Check, Writing content

   - You have the penalty of updating the DOM if data changed or did not change
2. Check, Writing content

   - You have the penalty of reading the HTML
   - You have penalty of updating DOM
3. Check, no write needed

   - You have the penalty of reading the HTML

Now Is the HTML most likely going to be different, the same, etc?

The solution depends on what you want to do. Caching the jQuery element will speed up the lookup/write. It will be slower than just a write.

Answer (score 1):

Init:

`var isBlank = true;`

`$('#my_span').html('my input is blank');`

keyup:

```
if(!isBlank){
    if( $('#my_input').val().length == 0){
        isBlank = true;
        $('#my_span').html('my input is blank');
    }
} else {
    if($('#my_input').val().length){
        isBlank = false;
        $('#my_span').html('my input is not blank');
    }
}
```

This way you are only manipulating the DOM if the state changes.

Also testing the length property may actually be faster than testing the string against "", because the interpreter won't have to create a String object from the string literal.

Answer (score -1):

How about saving the current value to a variable and just testing the variable to see if you have to change it. No messing with the DOM until you need to change it. (*You could also use a boolean named `isBlank` to get good effect here*):

```
var currValue;
if ( $('#my_input').val() == '' ) {
  if ( currValue != 'my input is blank' ) {
       currValue = 'my input is blank';
       $('#my_span').html(currValue);
  }
} else if ( currValue != 'My input is not blank' ) {
       currValue = 'My input is not blank';
       $('#my_span').html(currValue);
}
```

You also mentioned this is in the keydown event handler.

1. Don't forget to run this code one time at the start so it sets the display field to show the input field is blank to start with.
2. Don't forget that the user can select the text and right click to choose 'cut' and empty the field or choose 'paste' to add text to the field. Similarly, a drag and drop action can conceivably add or remove text.

**Alternate Train of Thought**

You might be better off with periodic, timed event that checks. Some people can type bursts of keys around 3 or 4 a second. If you timed it to look at the field every 1 second, you could cut down the short term slowdown due to this code running and replace it with a long term constant use of CPU cycles. But remember that there is no reason to not use CPU cycles if the computer isn't doing anything interesting.

Comment: @Ankit There is only a call to `html()` if the inner 'if' statement is true. That only happens when the saved display value is wrong. For exmaple, if there was content and now there isn't (because backspace was typed) OR if there was no content and now there is (because the letter 'a' was typed.)